# Empty body function in jquery.js - Rails 3.2 with jQuery-rails gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have been developing a rails app for a week now. I use jquery-rails gem to use jQuery and everything was working fine. But today, when I started the development server, jQuery just wasn't loading. The console gave the error `jQuery not defined` and `$ not defined` and so forth. So I checked if the jQuery files are being included and they were. But when I clicked on the link to the `jquery.js` file, it contained only the following.

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

jQuery just isnt working..

This is how I have required the js libraries:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require_tree .
```

I have tried interchanging bootstrap and jQuery and even tried removing jQuery and using only bootstrap. Nothing seems to be working.

The funny part is that it was working perfectly till last night!! And I don't remember adding or removing any js libs. I was only writing Javascript code. So I have no clue as to what went wrong overnight.

The only thing I haven't tried is serving jQuery from a CDN. But that is not an option considering where my app is going to be deployed.

Please help.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.beta'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'


#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
#gem 'devise'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
    gem 'less-rails'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'libv8'
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Okay I have figured out what went wrong. I created a controller called `jquery` to simply test some jquery plugins and thus a `jquery.js.coffee` file was created under `/assets/javascripts`. When I removed this file and deleted the controller, everything started working fine.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing

```
//= require jquery
```

in your manifest file, Rails will look for a file `jquery.js` in a few locations. These locations are defined in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`.

`jquery.js` and `jquery.js.coffee` are in this case both matches for `jquery.js` since Coffeescript compiles into Javascript.

When you had generated a controller called `jquery` and subsequently a `jquery.js.coffee` file alongside, the look–up for the referenced file `jquery.js` was already satisfied before Rails got to look into the vendor directories of included gems. Hence, the wrong file got included.

— Does this answer your (second) question?

Comment: Yes! I understand completely. Thank you very much.